# AngularFire $createUser() promise values does not include email

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

According to the AngularFire docs, the $createUser() onComplete callback returns

> ...an object containing attributes of the newly-created user, including the uid.

However, the userObject only contains the `uid` and nothing else. I was expecting an object similar to what is returned in the authentication callback (i.e. an additional `password` object containing an `email`, `isTemporaryPassword`, & `profileImageURL`).

I guess what I'm asking is, does the $createUser() onSuccess callback userObject contain anything other than the `uid`?

Comment: You can just console log and check it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the AngularFire Docs ([here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-users-and-authentication-createusercredentials)):

> Creates a new user account using an email / password combination. This function returns a promise that is resolved with an object containing user data about the created user. ***Currently, the object only contains the created user’s uid.***

So no, the $createUser() onSuccess callback userObject does not contain anything other than the User's uid?